# UnboundLocalError Exception Value: local variable 'first_name' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, django, model, mysql-error-1064

//views.py

from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from .models import insert_user

```
def index(request):
    return render(request,'backpages/index.html')

def register(request):
    if request.method=="POST":
        first_name=first_name.objects.get(first_name=request.POST['first_name'])


    email=email.objects.get(email=request.POST['email'])
    password=password.objects.get(password=request.POST['password'])


    user=insert_user(first_name=first_name,email=email,password=password)
    user.save()
    user=insert_user.objects.get(first_name=first_name,email=email,password=password)
    print ("user created.")
    return redirect('/')
else:
    return render(request,'backpages/register.html')
```

## Create your views here.

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, UserManager

class insert_user(AbstractBaseUser):

    first_name=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    email=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    password=models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to register your user your view should look like this

```
def register(request):
    if request.method=="POST":
        first_name=request.POST['first_name']
        email=request.POST['email']
        password=request.POST['password']


        user= insert_user.objects.create(
            first_name=first_name,
            email=email)
        user.set_password(password)

        user.save()

        print ("user created.")
        return redirect('/')
     return render(request,'backpages/register.html')
```

if you assing **password** `in insert_user.objects_create(` it will create the password in plain text. and you wont be able to log in with it, because django expects a hashed password, by the **SECRET_KEY** in your settings.py

when setting a password to an user you should use `.set_passwort('password123')`